# How can I find an element in an array whose index equals another element's value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an array of [5,4,0,3,1,6,2]. I take the first element at index 0, which has a value of 5. Next, I want to find the element whose index is 5. This corresponds to the value of 6. And then I want to find the value at index 6, which is 2, then 2 points to 0, and we're back to the beginning so we stop.

I need to like "chain" elements based on the index value, and find the length of a chain in my array. In my given example it would be 4. How can I do this? I feel like I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: Can you explain how you arrive at 3? I see `arr[0] = 5` -> `arr[5] = 6` -> `arr[6] = 2` -> `arr[2] = 9` -> `arr[9] = undefined` -> ???

Comment: Sorry, bad example... I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You could decide where to start (index zero in this case) and then set up a while loop that prints the current value and then sets the current value to the array lookup at that index. When the array lookup returns `undefined` stop. If you want the count, you can maintain a counter variable as you loop:

```js
let arr = [5,4,0,3,1,6,2]
let start = arr[0]
let seen = new Set();
let count = 0
while (start != undefined && !seen.has(start)){
    console.log(start)
    seen.add(start)
    count++
    start = arr[start]
}
console.log("Count:", count)
```

You could also keep a set of visited indexes to help avoid cycles. In this case if you started with index 1 it would just bounce between 1 and 4.

Comment: damn it, this is so obvious, i have NO idea why i got stuck on this problem. faackk. thank you!!

Comment: @emwhy --  l edited showing one way to avoid cycles and stop when get to a value you've seen already. You need something like that in the updated post to stop when you get back to index 0.

Answer (score 0):

One option is a `do/while` loop, which continually reassigns a `nextIndex` variable, which breaks once a duplicate `nextIndex` is found, or once the `nextIndex` is out of range of the array:

```js
const arr = [5, 4, 9, 3, 1, 6, 2];
let count = 0;
let nextIndex = 0;
const usedIndicies = new Set();
do {
  usedIndicies.add(nextIndex);
  nextIndex = arr[nextIndex];
  count++;
} while (!usedIndicies.has(nextIndex) && nextIndex < arr.length);
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also solve this via single [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
let arr = [5,4,0,3,1,6,2]

let result = arr.reduce((acc, cur, indx, arr) => {
  let last = acc[acc.length-1]
  !indx ? acc.push(cur) : !last ? null : acc.push(arr[last])
  return acc
}, [])

console.log('result: ', result, 'count: ', result.length)
```

And to further simplify this you can start always with the **first** element in the `accumulator array`:

```js
let arr = [5,4,0,3,1,6,2]

let result = arr.reduce((acc, cur, _, arr) => {
  let last = acc[acc.length - 1]
  last ? acc.push(arr[last]) : null
  return acc
}, [arr[0]])

console.log('result: ', result, 'count: ', result.length)
```

And further if you want you can one line it as:

```js
let arr = [5,4,0,3,1,6,2]

let r = arr.reduce((r, c, _, a) => 
   (r[r.length-1] ? r.push(a[r[r.length-1]]) : null, r), [arr[0]])

console.log('result: ', r, 'count: ', r.length)
```